# The best practice for developing app locally which then be deployed to Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Let's say I have a flask app, a PostgreSQL, and a Redis app. what is the best practice way to develop those apps locally which then later be deployed to Kubernetes.

Because, I have tried to develop in minikube with ksync, but I get difficulties in getting detailed debug log information.

Any ideas?

Comment: whats the problem with minikube?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple solutions for this (aka GitOps with Kubernetes):

- [Skaffold](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold)
- [Draft](https://github.com/Azure/draft)
- [Flux](https://github.com/weaveworks/flux) - IMO the most mature.
- [Ksonnet](https://ksonnet.io/)
- [GitKube](https://github.com/hasura/gitkube)
- [Argo](https://github.com/argoproj/argo) - A bit more of a workflow engine.
- [Metaparticle](https://github.com/metaparticle-io/) - Deploy with actual code.

Answer (score 1):

What we do with our systems is that we develop and test them locally. I am not very knowledgeable with Flask and ksyncy, but say for example, you are using [Lagom Microservices Framework](https://www.lagomframework.com/) in Java, you run you app locally using the SBT shell where you can view all your logs. We then automate the deployment using [LightBend Orchestration](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/lightbend-orchestration/current/).

When you then decide to test the app on Kubernetes, you can choose to use minikube, but you have to configure the logging properly. You can configure centralised logging for Kubernetes using the [EFK](https://blog.ptrk.io/how-to-deploy-an-efk-stack-to-kubernetes/) stack. This will collect all the logs from the various components of your app and store them in Elastic Search. You can then view these logs using The Kibana Dashboard. You can do a lot with the dashboard, you can view logs for a given period, or search logs by k8s namespace, or by container.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is using [skaffold](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold)

Comment: Check my answer :-)